# WKHTMLTOPDF Error on Image URL Source embedded in Email

Tags: python, wkhtmltopdf

I have code that has HTML files embedded in a directory on the C drive.

My python code will error out and not execute when trying to convert the HTML to PDF when the HTML file have images embedded that source to a HTTPS address. Anybody know any fixes?

Comment: @justinEzequiel Thanks for the resource. Unfortunately I think the sheer volume of PDF's will stop any manual process. We anticipate every user to archive around 100-200 html files a day

Comment: @justinEzequiel That is a tool used for reading already PDF documents. This script is converting HTML to PDF

Comment: Whoops, wrong thread/question. My bad. Let me delete my comments.

Comment: Whoops again. My first comment (now deleted unfortunately) applies. The approach still works. You just need to automate the steps. (It was my other subsequent comment which was for another question re non-searchable PDFs. Sorry.)

Comment: If you can post a snippet of the HTML, I'll see if I can find the time to replace the links with the base64-encoded versions.

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question and add a [mcve]? See also [ask].

Comment: @Robert The theoretical understanding is all I can provide due to the sensitivity of the data that I am working with. The question is stated in such a way that it is trivial to understand!

Comment: See [repl.it demo](https://repl.it/@JustinEzequiel/BlissfulSoftMarkuplanguage) re embedding images as base64.